# How to find the lub (supremum) and glb( Infimum) of such type of series?

Tags: real-analysis

Well there are a lot of ways of finding convergence and divergence but in finding the sum of the series you need some telescoping methods , and here is one series can you please tell me how to find its supremum (lub) and Infimum(glb)
1/2+1+1/8+1/4+1/32+1/16+1/128+1/64+....
Find supremum and Infimum as n approaches a( some fixed number )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the question is better prepared I will keep this answer short. In "sum" (haha) we can note the following:

If we write this as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$  we have
$$a_k = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2^k} &k  \text{ is odd}\\ \frac{1}{2^{k-2}} &k  \text{ is even}
\end{cases}$$ 
I leave the rest to the OP to sort out